# SVN merge failing

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN. The last time I merged trunk into my branch I had to merge some "mergeinfos", it was like a list of revisions with paths to single files. I selected the list with less entries (dunno why).

First my very simple tree:

> Trunk 
>   ----> branch1 
>   ----> branch2 
>   ----> mybranch

Now I try to merge the trunk again into my branch because of some new features I would like to have but it is not working. When I try to merge the first attempt stops after 3 or 4 files with conflicts and the merge stops. When I resolve the conflict and try to merge again something strange happens. All files are shown as tree conflicts and I only can "Accept current working status".

Is there an easy way to fix this problem? I don't care about my changes, I just want to fix my branch (fix svn). I have my changes locally and I can insert them later on again.

I already tried to export the trunk and replace the content of my branch with the content of the trunk, but the svn errors are still present.

Comment: YMMV but in my experience you can safely remove the `svn:mergeinfo` property from everywhere but the top level folders `trunk`, `branches/foo`, `branches/bar`... Having it in individual files serves no purpose and just gets on the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what has happened here without access to the repository, but I suspect your earlier trunk to branch merge is to blame. It sounds like you have mergeinfo in a messed up state in the branch and svn is barfing because of that.

> I don't care about my changes, I just want to fix my branch (fix svn). I
>   have my changes locally and I can insert them later on again.

In that case by far the easiest solution would be to abandon that branch, create a new one, and patch your changes in manually.

Otherwise:

- You might want to revert your previous merge (right click the checked out branch, choose svn log, right click the log entry for the last merge and choose to revert changes from this revision). Then commit the
  reversion, and then try merging from trunk again. This time, choose the mergeinfo
  which has more entries or if both sides have different paths manually
  edit so that the new mergeinfo contains the paths from both sides. Basically you are undoing the previous merge and having a second go at it.
- If that doesn't work or is too time consuming, try another merge from
  trunk to branch but **only the revision numbers you have already merged** (press the Log button to choose the revisions), and tick the "Only record the merge" checkbox. This will
  hopefully fix any issues in your mergeinfo. Commit the record-only
  merge and then merge trunk to branch again to pick up the latest
  changes.